# Adding an event handler to custom control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I have created a custom control (Check Box) with a custom EventHandler

```
Public Event CheckedChanged As EventHandler

Private Sub setCheckStateUI(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   ...
   RaiseEvent CheckedChanged(sender, e)
End Sub
```

It works fine without any errors if I added this control directly to a form. But when I add this to another custom control (a page of settings window) and that second custom control add to a form (settings window) the 'settings window' freeze and visual studio auto restart.

If I removed this **event handler** in the code the problem is gone.

What can be the problem here?

Thanks in advance

**Update:** (Complete code of the Custom Control)

```
Public Class cusCheckBox
Private mystring As String
Private CheckButtonState As Integer = 0

Public Event CheckedChanged As EventHandler

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    mystring = Me.Name
    setSizes()
End Sub

Public Property CheckState() As Integer
    Get
        CheckState = CheckButtonState
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        CheckButtonState = value
        chkButton.CheckState = CheckButtonState
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LabelText() As String
    Get
        LabelText = mystring
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mystring = value
        lblText.Text = mystring
        setSizes()
    End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Property Font As Font
    Get
        Return lblText.Font
    End Get
    Set(value As Font)
        lblText.Font = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub chkButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkButton.CheckedChanged
    If chkButton.CheckState = 1 Then
        chkButton.Image = Global.MYLogs.My.Resources.Resources.btnToggleOn
        CheckButtonState = 1
    Else
        chkButton.Image = Global.MYLogs.My.Resources.Resources.btnToggleOff
        CheckButtonState = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblText.Click
    setCheckStateUI(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub cusCheckBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    setCheckStateUI(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub cusCheckBox_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    setCheckStateUI(sender, e)
    setSizes()
End Sub


Private Sub cusCheckBox_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    setSizes()
End Sub

Private Sub setSizes()
    Me.Size = New Size(chkButton.Width + lblText.Width + 4, chkButton.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub setCheckStateUI(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If chkButton.CheckState = 0 Then
        chkButton.Image = Global.MYLogs.My.Resources.Resources.btnToggleOn
        chkButton.CheckState = 1
        CheckButtonState = 1
    Else
        chkButton.Image = Global.MYLogs.My.Resources.Resources.btnToggleOff
        chkButton.CheckState = 0
        CheckButtonState = 0
    End If

    RaiseEvent CheckedChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)

    chkButton.Select()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: That code is wrong. At the very least, you should be passing `Me` rather than `sender`. You should learn the proper pattern for raising your own events. Try [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank u for the link it's a very knowledgeable blog to read. I changed `sender` to `Me` but still got the same problem.

Comment: How is that `setCheckStateUI` method being invoked? Is it handling an event of a child control? Please provide all details relating to that. If you can, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jmcilhinney I update the question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I fond the error, calling `SetCheckStateUI` in `cusCheckBox_Load` is wrong. thank you for leading me to the answer.